# Identifying EXIF Tampering

Tags: forensics

Is it really impossible to detect changes to EXIF data? Reading from this link, it seems that it is not possible to detect EXIF changes:  https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43150/how-to-detect-if-a-photos-metadata-has-been-changed

I thought I should ask the question in this forum as we have more security experts here. I am just not convinced that there is no way to identify that an EXIF information has been tampered with. Do you know a way to identify changes to an EXIF data? In our case the images are taken with mobile devices.

Comment: AFAIK, in your case it's impossible (if you don't code yourself the app taking the photo). If you want to be able to do so, you will need to add some watermark to your image (like a signature of the EXIF data). That's the only way I can see. You will not be able to detect it if the image was not issued by you. I can remember a company who tried to do that directly in the camera they were selling but, indeed someone reversed the firmware and got the key...

Comment: Related: Photo-SE: [Can digital cameras sign images to prove authenticity?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15307/can-digital-cameras-sign-images-to-prove-authenticity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## EXIF can't be trusted.

> I am just not convinced that there is no way to identify that an EXIF information has been tampered with.

It's hard to prove a negative. But I think your just as our of luck here as you are with trying to prove that an ASCII text file has not been altered: no way of doing that.

You don't own the camera, the camera is dumb and has to rely on someone to operate it.

So if that someone *lies* to the camera, then the camera has no way of telling. And neither  have you afterwards.

So unless there are some gross inconsistencies somewhere (e.g. EXIF says "no flash fired" when it's obviously flash photography, e.g. EXIF-GPS reporting location as the North Pole when there's palm trees in the picture, etc.) you have no real way of finding out.

I think EXIF was meant to be more of a convenience feature, rather than a trust feature.

So it's pretty much like the date stamp that some analog cameras used to put on photos:
It's nice to have but easy to fake if you set the camera to the wrong date on purpose or if you take a photo with no time stamp enabled and then later add one when you make a copy.

Answer (score 2):

With computer data in general there is only two ways of being able to detect tampering:

- A: Check if your file / data differs from the original and untempered version. You obviously need to have the original file / data for this.
- B: Check if your file's / data's hash is the same as the original one's. You need to have the original's hash for this.

While only the above methods can give a verifiable good answer that will hold in court (as that's the main reason for the existence of forensics - hence the name), it is possible to make educated guesses based on the unknown file's EXIF data and content.
(For example EXIF data claiming the picture has been taken in 2000 and the picture clearly showing something that **verifiably** did not exist around that time **might** indicate that the image has been tampered with. OR it might indicate that the image was created with a software that [has strange quirks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50001/iphone-exif-gps-timestamp-appears-to-be-based-on-local-settings).)